# functions and recursions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, recursion

The sequence s(k) where k=1,2,3.... satisfies the recursion s(n)=s(n−2)+s(n−3) for n≥4.

If s(n) is rewritten in the form

s(n)=s(n−1)+S(n0,n1,…) 
where S(n0,n1,…) is some linear combination of terms s(nk) and nk=n−k, what would that linear combination be and what would the minimum value of n have to be?

I do not know where to begin such a problem. I first started with reducing the given function, however that led to nowhere.

This problem was presented in a competition. What is the result, or what are some steps that could lead to a solution?

Comment: Why is this post locked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$ s(n)=s(n−2)+s(n−3) $,
then
$ s(n-1)=s(n−3)+s(n−4) $
so
$ s(n-3)=s(n−1)-s(n−4) $
so that
$s(n) = s(n-2)+s(n-1)-s(n-4)
=s(n-1)+s(n-2)-s(n-4)
$.

Comment: Pefect, Thank you. Just for understanding, what would n have to be greater than or equal to be? It was 4 in the first recursion

Comment: My recursion goes one deeper (n-4 instead of n-3), so n would have to start one later.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not seem to understand, could you rephrase it? Would n have to be greater than or equal to five?

Comment: Yes, since 5=4+1.